# Mysqlbackup Syntax for Incremental Using Cron

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

New to mysqlbackup command.  I have a database, let's call it db1 that I want to do incremental backups on once an hour with a 24 hour rotation on.  Wondering the best strategy and syntax to use.  I would expect it to be an hourly cron event but then there's the issue of the incrementals getting larger as the base full backup ages.  You could erase the full backup and redo it, but then I would lose the last 23 hours of incrementals.   So maybe what I really need is a differential scheme?

Actually, going back more than the last hour's backup is not going to be necessary so I suppose on the 24th hour deleting everything and starting over would work but seems a little clunky way to do things.

Comment: you mean to backup a day data and then flush the DB tables?

Comment: No. I mean I want to be able to restore the database with only a maximum of one hour of data loss should it become corrupt or an accidental deletion.